# How to make Response as Singleton in API testing framework?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm working on API testing framework with Java and Rest Assured. The Response created in BaseTest and used in all test cases inherited from BaseTest. Is there any way to make Response as a Singleton?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, you can't b/c response is created by Rest-Assured, not your code. And counter question, why do you need that? Response is different from time to time, how can they be the same in order to make it Singleton. Pershaps you don't understand Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a good idea to mention what kind of benefit you expect from the change. It seems like you are mixing the concepts a bit.
The Response is returned type from the Rest Assured.
When you say the response is created in BaseTest you probably reffer to a specific response, login or something that is needed for all other requests/tests.